# Rewrite all virtual subdomains to same folder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have been searching the internet trying to find a solution to this problem but cannot find a definite solution.

I am trying to <strike>redirect</strike> rewrite

> anything.domain.com/anypage.php?sub=anything&including=get_parameters

to

> domain.com/users/anypage.php?sub=anything&including=get_parameters

---

I have found several pages with possible solutions but they all differ slightly to my needs, and editing them continually ends in failure.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

P.S Wildcard DNS are enabled and everything is set up correctly in apache.

**Edit:**

I ended up using the folowing, it seems to work pretty well. Thanks.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
^(.*).domain.com RewriteCond
%{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$
http://domain.com/users/$1?sub=%1 [P]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/users/$1?sub=%1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

# redirect for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/users/$1?sub=%1 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

R=301 will redirect with https status 301
L will make last rule
NE is for no escaping query string
QSA will append your existing query parameters

$1 is your REQUEST_URI
```

Comment: I should have specified in the question, by 'anything', I mean that this value will be a variable (The users username to be exact).

Comment: You don't have to escape the . within squared brackets to use the literal value. But this should work. And also add `users/` in front of the `$1`.to match the example. Nice point adding HTTPS.

Comment: @anubhava : thank you very much for your help with this. However, I found a solution which caters for all my need. I have added the final working solution to my original question. Thanks

Comment: @Myv: Thanks for your suggestions, I have modified my answer as you suggested.

Comment: @Myv: Many thanks for your good suggestions. @dave e: There are few issues in your suggested solution. **1)** `.` must be escaped outside square brackets otherwise `.` means *any character* hence conditions `foo.domain.com` will also match `foo-domain-com`. **2)** You may not need it but there is NO https handling in your answer. **3)** Following your rule a URL of `http://foo.domain.com/` will become `http://domain.com/users//?sub=foo` with double slash. **4)** Since you are not using QSA flag your original query string will be lost after redirection.