# my mod-rewrite to change urls is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to replace my.example.com/newsletter.php or example.com/newsletter.php to be example.com/newsletter/

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

and what if I want http://example.com/communities/index.php?sub_id=1

to be a specific name like http://example.com/communities/Bridlewood/

possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are right about the leading slash, and you should catch the possibility of a trailing slash (bearing in mind that '$' marks the end of a string .

Try something like this:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ /$1.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Note: The `QSA` flag stands for 'query string append' and will pass any url query on to the relevant page.

hth

EDIT: For URL's that contain characters other than lower case alpha's you should change the range group, use a case-insensitive switch or simply use `(.*)` as per other peoples examples!

Comment: +1 for the trailing slash. The example given by @Adam use it, but his rewrite rule doesn't include it.

Comment: The specific name thing would get tricky very quickly! If you wanted all of your pages to use this method you'd end up having to write a rule for each page! You'd be better off creating a separate page to handle the ID based redirecting, accepting the URL param as a string then switching header location out to the correct 'id' based page. This would require only one or two mod_rewrite rules to pass the URL parameter to the page_handler file.

Comment: the guy running my server says he's running WindowsIIS... im guessing mod-rewrite does not work? there must be an equivalent

Comment: Ahh!! Then google is your friend, you must search for answers young padawan (sorry it's getting late and it's been a long day). But you could look at http://www.helicontech.com/download-isapi_rewrite3.htm -- They offer a 'freeware' version but please consider the limitations! --- OR find out if your host offers Apache based servers as well and request your site to be transferred. Many hosts offer both Windows IIS and WAMP/LAMP based servers. If you've got a nice, friendly host they should be happy to oblige and if they're very good it may all be done, DNS and all, within a week!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check that what was requested doesn't actually exist otherwise you'll be in all kinds of trouble! Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /$1.php
```

As for performing the second thing you ask, you'll obviously need to have a lookup function in your PHP code to get the id of the item you're after. Make sure you don't actually have a `/communities` directory first.

There's plenty of help in the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here: [Rewrite all virtual subdomains to same folder using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657791/rewrite-all-virtual-subdomains-to-same-folder-using-htaccess/5657822#5657822) Pretty much same as what you are trying to do here.